# isc-dhcp-server response not being sent over a wireless bridge

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, dhcp

I am trying to add some WiFi access points to my network.  When I set them up they default to being being routers, but I want them to be set as a bridge.  When they are working as routing, they work ok.  But when I set them up to be a bridge instead of a wireless router, my wireless devices are not getting a DHCP response from my DHCP server.  I am using isc-dhcp-server and here is my setup

```
# The ddns-updates-style parameter controls whether or not the server will      
# attempt to do a DNS update when a lease is confirmed. We default to the       
# behavior of the version 2 packages ('none', since DHCP v2 didn't              
# have support for DDNS.)                                                       
ddns-update-style none;
# static domain_name_servers=192.168.42.206;                                    

# option definitions common to all supported networks...                        
ddns-update-style interim;
ignore client-updates;
update-static-leases on;
include "/etc/dhcp/rndc.key";
update-optimization on;
update-conflict-detection on;
# include "/etc/dhcp/rndc.conf";                                                                                                                                             

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local                 
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.                   
authoritative;

# Use this to send dhcp log messages to a different log file (you also          
# have to hack syslog.conf to complete the redirection).                        
log-facility local7;

subnet 192.168.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
       range 192.168.42.100 192.168.42.254;
       option routers 192.168.42.1;
       option broadcast-address 192.168.42.255;
       option domain-name-servers 192.168.42.206;
}
```

The network map that is important is

```
Router -> wireless access point -> devices connection to wireless access point (not getting IP addr)
||  |
||  v
||DNS server (static IP address)
|L-------------> Devices on the wired network (get their DHCP requests responces and get an IP addr)
v
DHCP server
```

The DHCP server is seeing the request as per the log files

```
Feb 14 21:06:18 pi1 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 08:12:a5:3b:00:69 via eth0
Feb 14 21:06:19 pi1 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.42.179 to 08:12:a5:3b:00:69 via eth0
Feb 14 21:06:21 pi1 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:e0:4c:d6:69:02 via eth0
Feb 14 21:06:22 pi1 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.42.199 to 00:e0:4c:d6:69:02 via eth0
Feb 14 21:06:36 pi1 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from ec:fa:bc:87:98:86 (ESP_879886) via eth0
Feb 14 21:06:37 pi1 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.42.253 to ec:fa:bc:87:98:86 (ESP_879886) via eth0
```

But the devices are saying failed to get DHCP response.

Wireless access point is a Eero (a wifi mesh network device) Model # J010001

isc-dhcp-server is running off of a Raspberry Pi, and the DNS server is a Pi-Hole on another Rasberry Pi.

I am willing to provide more info if needed, just ask and I will edit question with needed info.

I will note that for devices on the wireless that I can set a static IP address they can access the full network, it just the ones that don't let me set an IP address but require a DHCP server can not get a DHCP response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DHCP can be a challenge.  But is oh-so-nice (compared to fully using static IP addresses).

Your DHCP server is apparently receiving the DISCOVER, or it wouldn't have made an OFFER.  You didn't say anything about a REQUEST (which would be followed by an acknowledgement).  So maybe that OFFER didn't reach the client (or maybe there was a request that somehow didn't make it).

Given the setup, from Wi-Fi client to WAP (Wi-Fi Access Point) through another router and a DHCP server, there's no way that's going to get all the way from the Wi-Fi client to the DHCP server if the WAP is in routing mode, without help.  A simple DHCP Client <-> DHCP Server communication cannot cross routers.  What happens is that the DHCP Server responds to the DHCP Client using the MAC-48 address.  The DHCP Server cannot respond to the DHCP client using IP because the DHCP client doesn't even have an IP address (other than 0.0.0.0).  Communication based on MAC-48 addresses don't cross over routers into other subnets; a working IP address is needed for that.

(Note that a DHCP Client might have a working IP address when it is trying to contact a DHCP Server if it is trying to renew a lease.  But the protocol was designed in a way that doesn't rely on the DHCP Client's IP address, which is good since the DHCP client doesn't really have a decent IP Address in some other scenarios.)

So when your WAP was acting as a router, it must have been helping the process.  Either it was acting as a DHCP server itself, or if was acting as a DHCP Relay.  A DHCP Relay acts kind of like a DHCP server, in that it receives requests from the DHCP client and can respond to the DHCP client using the DHCP client's MAC-48 address.  The big difference is that a DHCP Relay doesn't have it's own database of details about what addresses to hand out, and doesn't need to keep track of which addresses have already been handed out for other leases.  Instead, the DHCP Relay will communicate to the DHCP Server, and the DHCP server handles those elaborate details.

The DHCP Relay <-> DHCP Server communication can use IP addresses to relay traffic through routers and to other subnets.  That works fine, because the DHCP Relay is often a part of the infrastructure, and so it may typically have its own long-term IP address.

Now, you might think that if routing DHCP traffic is a problem, then converting a WAP from a router into a bridge would simplify things.  And my inclination would be to agree with such a concept.

However, when flipping to a bridge, the WAP's primary role may not require as much usage of IP addresses, and it may rely more on MAC-48 addresses.  A bridge can happily pass long a DHCP client's communications that use a MAC-48 address.  So the bridge may have shut down its DHCP Relay functionality (and/or stopped acting as an additional/rogue DHCP server).

In likelihood, this would cause the DHCP Client's initial DHCP request to be seen by the device that your diagram calls a "router".  Now, if that router isn't acting as a DHCP Server or a DHCP Relay, then the DHCP Client's DCHP requests might not be getting handled.

Even if the DHCP Client's request did somehow make it to the DHCP Server (since outgoing traffic often works better, getting handled nicely by NAT, etc.), the DHCP server might not know how to get the OFFER (and/or ACKNOWLEDGEMENT) passed the router to the DHCP Client which is expecting a response to its MAC-48 address.

So, if you want the WAP to act as a bridge, it might also be appropriate to make sure the Router knows how to handle a DHCP Client, using DHCP Relay functionality.  (An alternative could be for the router to be a DHCP Server.  This might be best done by using addresses from a different subnet, and then routing would need to be handled well.)

Comment: So, in summary, I'm not sure I correctly identified the actual problem.  But, I might have.  And even if I didn't, maybe some of these details will help you determine what's going on, and help lead you to whatever the actual issue is.  Using traffic sniffing, e.g. TCP Dump / PCAP files / WireShark, might help determine what traffic is actually reaching which network interface on which device.

Comment: The WAP is not in router mode I have set it up as bridge mode.  But there is a lot of good info there (but it not getting though the access point even in bridge mode)

Comment: This did lead me the the solution, I had a run away process flooding the network, once I found that, and killed it, everything just worked.